# Splitting a JS array into N arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Imagine I have an JS array like this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
```

What I want is to split that array into N smaller arrays. For instance:

```
split_list_in_n(a, 2)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]

For N = 3:
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]

For N = 4:
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11]]

For N = 5:
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]]
```

For Python, I have this:

```
def split_list_in_n(l, cols):
    """ Split up a list in n lists evenly size chuncks """
    start = 0
    for i in xrange(cols):
        stop = start + len(l[i::cols])
        yield l[start:stop]
        start = stop
```

For JS, the best right solution that I could come up with is a recursive function, but I don't like it because it's complicated and ugly. This inner function returns an array like this [1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5, 6, null, 7, 8], and then I have to loop it again and split it manually. (My first attempt was returning this: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9]]], and I decided to do it with the null separator).

```
function split(array, cols) {
    if (cols==1) return array;
    var size = Math.ceil(array.length / cols);
    return array.slice(0, size).concat([null]).concat(split(array.slice(size), cols-1));
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle of that: http://jsfiddle.net/uduhH/

How would you do that? Thanks!

Comment: related to - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40166199/104380

Comment: Your `split` function is not far off.  You can remove the `null` business by adding two array wrappers: `if (cols == 1) return [array]` and `return [array.slice(0, size)].concat(split(array.slice(size), cols-1))`.  I find this recursive version much more readable than most of the answers here.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can make the slices "balanced" (subarrays' lengths differ as less as possible) or "even" (all subarrays but the last have the same length):

```js
function chunkify(a, n, balanced) {
    
    if (n < 2)
        return [a];

    var len = a.length,
            out = [],
            i = 0,
            size;

    if (len % n === 0) {
        size = Math.floor(len / n);
        while (i < len) {
            out.push(a.slice(i, i += size));
        }
    }

    else if (balanced) {
        while (i < len) {
            size = Math.ceil((len - i) / n--);
            out.push(a.slice(i, i += size));
        }
    }

    else {

        n--;
        size = Math.floor(len / n);
        if (len % size === 0)
            size--;
        while (i < size * n) {
            out.push(a.slice(i, i += size));
        }
        out.push(a.slice(size * n));

    }

    return out;
}


///////////////////////

onload = function () {
    function $(x) {
        return document.getElementById(x);
    }

    function calc() {
        var s = +$('s').value, a = [];
        while (s--)
            a.unshift(s);
        var n = +$('n').value;
        $('b').textContent = JSON.stringify(chunkify(a, n, true))
        $('e').textContent = JSON.stringify(chunkify(a, n, false))
    }

    $('s').addEventListener('input', calc);
    $('n').addEventListener('input', calc);
    calc();
}
```

```html
<p>slice <input type="number" value="20" id="s"> items into
<input type="number" value="6" id="n"> chunks:</p>
<pre id="b"></pre>
<pre id="e"></pre>
```

Comment: Your solution is neat, it does same thing that my recursive solution does but without all that mess. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @georg,  can you please explain this line : 

`var size = Math.ceil((len - i) / n--);`

Comment: @dpg5000: when slicing the next chunk, its size is the number of remaining elements (`len - i`) by the number of remaining chunks (`n--`)

Comment: Hi @georg thank you.  How would I modify this code to ensure that all sub-arrays are of equal length except for the last subarray (unless of course the divisor results in no remainder, whereby all subarrays would be equal).  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can we get a Tyescript version?

Comment: @cbdeveloper: here you go `function chunkify<T>(a: T[], n: number, balanced: boolean): T[][]`

Answer (score 62):

I think this way using splice is the cleanest:

```js
function splitToNChunks(array, n) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        result.push(array.splice(0, Math.ceil(array.length / i)));
    }
    return result;
}

// Example:

const example = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

console.log(splitToNChunks([...example], 3))
console.log(splitToNChunks([...example], 5))
```

For example, for `n = 3`, you would take 1/3, then 1/2 of the remaining part, then the rest of the array. `Math.ceil` ensures that in case of uneven number of elements they will go to the earliest chunks.

(Note: calling `.splice` on an array will directly change its length. To avoid destroying your initial array, you can use its temporary shallow copy instead: `const copiedArray = [ ...originalArray ]`)

Comment: This solution worked for me. Just one suggestion. In order to not destroy the initial array, add this line `const copyArray = array.map(v => v);` to create a shallow copy of the array. Then manipulate the copied array in the rest of the function instead.

Comment: A little modification. It would also create a copy.
``const copyArray = [...array]``

Answer (score 19):

```js
function split(array, n) {
  let [...arr]  = array;
  var res = [];
  while (arr.length) {
    res.push(arr.splice(0, n));
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: This does not works as expected for n = 5 and arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11].

Comment: this doesn't split to n subarrays, merely to subarrays of n length.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: to solve the OPs question you use this with split(arr, Math.ceil(arr.length/chunkCount)) I guess... but I came here looking for splits into N-sized chunks so this fit perfectly :)

Answer (score 16):

I just made an iterative implementation of the algorithm: http://jsfiddle.net/ht22q/. It passes your test cases.

```
function splitUp(arr, n) {
    var rest = arr.length % n, // how much to divide
        restUsed = rest, // to keep track of the division over the elements
        partLength = Math.floor(arr.length / n),
        result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += partLength) {
        var end = partLength + i,
            add = false;

        if(rest !== 0 && restUsed) { // should add one element for the division
            end++;
            restUsed--; // we've used one division element now
            add = true;
        }

        result.push(arr.slice(i, end)); // part of the array

        if(add) {
            i++; // also increment i in the case we added an extra element for division
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: (This works as expected, but I can only choose one answer as correct) Hi! Thanks for helping. Nice thinking about how to use the rest.

Answer (score 10):

You can reduce it into a matrix. The example below split the array (`arr`) into a matrix of two-positions arrays. If you want other sizes just change the 2 value on the second line:

```
target.reduce((memo, value, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0 && index !== 0) memo.push([])
  memo[memo.length - 1].push(value)
  return memo
}, [[]])
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Because some people is still commenting this doesn't answer the question since I was fixing the **size of each chunk instead of the number of chunks** I want. Here it comes the code explaining what I'm trying to explain in the comments section: Using the `target.length`.

```js
// Chunk function

const chunk = (target, size) => {
  return target.reduce((memo, value, index) => {
    // Here it comes the only difference
    if (index % (target.length / size) == 0 && index !== 0) memo.push([])
    memo[memo.length - 1].push(value)
    return memo
  }, [[]])
}

// Usage

write(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
write(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4], 4))

// For rendering pruposes. Ignore
function write (content) { document.write(JSON.stringify(content), '</br>') }
```

Comment: Wow nice and concise way to do this! Love it! Great job! :-)

Comment: I love this technique, but it's not answering the question. It returns any amount of x-sized chunks, whereas the questions was asking for x amount of evenly-sized chunks.

Comment: Love this !!! I've refactored to return evenly-sized chunks  `function splitArr(arr, n) {
    return arr.reduce(function (a, i) {
        if (a[a.length - 1].length >= arr.length / n) { a.push([]) }
        a[a.length - 1].push(i)
        return a;
    }, [[]])
}`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, it's about **fixed** size of chunks, not fixed size of items-per-chunk

Comment: @vsync you know you can divide? right? Something like `array.length / numberOfArraysIWant`.

Comment: @vsync ok, whatever

Comment: definitely does not answer the question.

Comment: Concise and really clever, my preferred way to solve this and a whole other cases with this simple pattern, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

#### Update: 7/21/2020

The answer I've given a few years ago only works if `originalArray.length` <= `numCols`. You could alternatively use something like this function below, but that will create a layout that doesn't quite match the question at hand (horizontal sorting rather than vertical sorting). AKA: `[1,2,3,4]` -> `[[1,4],[2],[3]]`. I understand this might still provide value so I'll leave this here, but I recommend [Senthe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514813/1322810).

```js
function splitArray(flatArray, numCols){
  const newArray = []
  for (let c = 0; c < numCols; c++) {
    newArray.push([])
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < flatArray.length; i++) {
    const mod = i % numCols
    newArray[mod].push(flatArray[i])
  }
  return newArray
}
```

#### Original Answer from 2017:

Old question, but since vanillaJS is not a requirement and so many are trying to solve this with lodash/chunk, and without mistaking what `_.chunk` actually does, here's a concise + accurate solution using `lodash`:

(Unlike the accepted answer, this also guarantees n columns even if `originalArray.length` < `numCols`)

```
import _chunk from 'lodash/chunk'

/**
 * Split an array into n subarrays (or columns)
 * @param  {Array} flatArray Doesn't necessarily have to be flat, but this func only works 1 level deep
 * @param  {Number} numCols   The desired number of columns
 * @return {Array}
 */
export function splitArray(flatArray, numCols){
  const maxColLength = Math.ceil(flatArray.length/numCols)
  const nestedArray = _chunk(flatArray, maxColLength)
  let newArray = []
  for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    newArray[i] = nestedArray[i] || []
  }
  return newArray
}
```

The `for` loop at the end is what guarantees the desired number of "columns".

Comment: This fails when array length is 4 and numCols is 3. Tried with splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3) and it returns [[1, 2], [3, 4], []].

Comment: You're absolutely right @PratikKulshreshth. I'll update the answer. For any interested, I like Senthe's answer the best now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51514813/1322810

Answer (score 7):

Mutation is, generally speaking, a Bad Thing™.

This is nice, clean, and idempotent.

```js
function partition(list = [], n = 1) {
  const isPositiveInteger = Number.isSafeInteger(n) && n > 0;
  if (!isPositiveInteger) {
    throw new RangeError('n must be a positive integer');
  }

  const partitions = [];
  const partitionLength = Math.ceil(list.length / n);

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += partitionLength) {
    const partition = list.slice(i, i+partitionLength);
    partitions.push( partition );
  }

  return partitions;
}
```

[Edited to add]

Here's another flavor where the caller specifies the partition size rather than the number of partitions to be created:

```js
function partition(list = [], n = 1) {
  const isPositiveInteger = Number.isSafeInteger(n) && n > 0;
  if (!isPositiveInteger) {
    throw new RangeError('n must be a positive integer');
  }

  const partitions = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += n) {
    const partition = list.slice(i, i+n);
    partitions.push( partition );
  }

  return partitions;
}
```

And if you want that to be "balanced" such that the individual chunks will differ in length by no more than 1, that only requires a little math.

To distribute, say M things into N buckets in that manner, we need to first determine the quotient Q and remainder R of M / N.

Let Q denote the basic partition length. R will always be less than N, and is the number of excess items that need to be distributed across all the partitions. Ergo, the first R partitions will contain Q+1 items and the remaining partitions will contain Q items.

For example, to partition a list of 100 items into 8 buckets, we get:

M = 10
N = 8
Q = 12
R = 4

So we will get:

- 4 (R) buckets of Q+1 (13) items, and
- 4 (N-R) buckets of Q (12) items

And 4 * 13 + 4 * 12 reduces to 52+48, or 100.

That leads us to this:

```js
function partition(list = [], n = 1) {
  const isPositiveInteger = Number.isSafeInteger(n) && n > 0;
  if (!isPositiveInteger) {
    throw new RangeError('n must be a positive integer');
  }

  const q = Math.floor( list.length / n );
  const r = list.length % n;

  let i   ; // denotes the offset of the start of the slice
  let j   ; // denotes the zero-relative partition number
  let len ; // denotes the computed length of the slice

  const partitions = [];
  for ( i=0, j=0, len=0; i < list.length; i+=len, ++j ) {
    len = j < r ? q+1 : q ;
    const partition = list.slice( i, i+len ) ; 
    partitions.push( partition ) ;
  }

  return partitions;
}
```

Comment: Your code is great! We need to pass how many chunks we need to divide our array into but the way to specify how many elements we need per chunk needs to be calculated by our self I.e. `partition(arr, Math.round(arr.length / n))` where `arr` is the actual array and `n` is the max number of elements allowed per cunk.

Answer (score 6):

If you happen to know the size of the chunks you want beforehand, there's a pretty elegant ES6 way of doing this:

```js
const groupsOfFour = ([a,b,c,d, ...etc]) =>
  etc.length? [[a,b,c,d], ...groupsOfFour(etc)] : [[a,b,c,d]];
  
console.log(groupsOfFour([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]));
```

I find this notation pretty useful for, for example parsing RGBA out of a `Uint8ClampedArray`.

Comment: Except that this fails for n < 4: `groupsOfFour( [ 1 ] )` returns `[ 1 , undefined, undefined, undefined ]`, rather than the expected (and desired) `[ [1] ]`.

Comment: you want `groupsOfFour` to return a group of one? might have the wrong function

Answer (score 3):

Another recursive works quite well, it is less ugly

```
function nSmaller(num, arr, sliced) {

    var mySliced = sliced || [];
    if(num === 0) {
        return sliced;
    }

    var len = arr.length,
        point = Math.ceil(len/num),
        nextArr = arr.slice(point);

    mySliced.push(arr.slice(0, point));
    nSmaller(num-1, nextArr, mySliced);

    return(mySliced);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function splitArray(arr, numOfParts = 10){
        const splitedArray = []
        for (let i = 0; i < numOfParts;i++) {
            const numOfItemsToSplice = arr.length / numOfParts;
            splitedArray.push(arr.splice(0, numOfItemsToSplice))
        }
        return splitedArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursive approach, not tested.

```
function splitArray(array, parts, out) {
    var
        len = array.length
        , partLen

    if (parts < len) {
        partLen = Math.ceil(len / parts);
        out.push(array.slice(0, partLen));
        if (parts > 1) {
            splitArray(array.slice(partLen), parts - 1, out);
        }
    } else {
        out.push(array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Partition

```js
const partition = (x,n) => {
  const p=x.length%n, q=Math.ceil(x.length/n), r=Math.floor(x.length/n);
  return [...Array(n)].reduce((a,_,i)=>(a[0].push(x.slice(a[1],(a[1]+=i<p?q:r))),a),[[],0])[0];
};
```

**DEMO**

```js
// to make it consistent to filter pass index and array as arguments
const partition = (x,n) => {
    const p = x.length % n,q = Math.ceil(x.length / n),r = Math.floor(x.length / n);
    return [...Array(n)].reduce((a,_,i)=>(a[0].push(x.slice(a[1],(a[1]+=i<p?q:r))),a),[[],0])[0];
};

console.log(partition([], 3))
console.log(partition([1, 2], 3))
console.log(partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3))
console.log(partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3))
```

### For Typescript

```
const partition = <T>(x: T[], n: number) => {
    const p = x.length % n, q = Math.ceil(x.length / n), r = Math.floor(x.length / n);
    return [...Array(n) as never[]].reduce((a, _, i) =>
        (a[0].push(x.slice(a[1], a[1] += i < p ? q : r)), a)
        , [[], 0] as [T[][], number])[0]
}
```

### ONE-LINER Partition (but different order)

```js
const part=(x,n)=>x.reduce((a,v,i)=>(a[i%n].push(v),a),[...Array(n)].map(()=>[]));
```

**DEMO**

```js
// to make it consistent to filter pass index and array as arguments
const part=(x,n)=>x.reduce((a,v,i)=>(a[i%n].push(v),a),[...Array(n)].map(()=>[]));

console.log(part([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3));
console.log(part([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
console.log(part([1, 2], 3));
```

### For Typescript

```
const part = <T>(array: T[], parts: number) =>
  array.reduce(
    (acc, value, i) => (acc[i % parts].push(value), acc),
    [...Array(parts)].map(() => []) as T[][]
  );
```

Comment: small fix for ts `const partition = <T,>(x: T[], n: number) => {`

Answer (score 1):

Just use lodash' chunk function to split the array into smaller arrays https://lodash.com/docs#chunk No need to fiddle with the loops anymore!

Comment: The question asks how to solve this using vannila js, not using js libraries

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I didn't know lodash had this.

Comment: This also doesn't answer the question. He wants N arrays, not arrays of N elements.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleaner approach would be the following (without using any other library) :

```
var myArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  myArray.push(i+1);
}
console.log(myArray);

function chunk(arr, size){
  var chunkedArr = [];
  var noOfChunks = Math.ceil(arr.length/size);
  console.log(noOfChunks);
  for(var i=0; i<noOfChunks; i++){
    chunkedArr.push(arr.slice(i*size, (i+1)*size));
  }
   return chunkedArr;
}

var chunkedArr = chunk(myArray, 3);
console.log(chunkedArr);
```

I have created my own array which is to be chunked. You can find the code [here](https://jsbin.com/ficicop/1/edit?js,console)

Also we have a method "chunk" in the lodash library which is of great use. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way, it works...

```
function splitArray(array, parts) {
    if (parts< array.length && array.length > 1 && array != null) {
        var newArray = [];
        var counter1 = 0;
        var counter2 = 0;

        while (counter1 < parts) {
            newArray.push([]);
            counter1 += 1;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            newArray[counter2++].push(array[i]);
            if (counter2 > parts - 1)
                counter2 = 0;
        }

        return newArray;
    } else 
        return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check my version of this array split

```
// divide array
Array.prototype.divideIt = function(d){
    if(this.length <= d) return this;
    var arr = this,
        hold = [],
        ref = -1;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(i % d === 0){
            ref++;
        }
        if(typeof hold[ref] === 'undefined'){
            hold[ref] = [];
        }
        hold[ref].push(arr[i]);
    }

    return hold;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know wanna set child_arrays.length then i think this solution best:

```
function sp(size, arr){ //size - child_array.length
    var out = [],i = 0, n= Math.ceil((arr.length)/size); 
    while(i < n) { out.push(arr.splice(0, (i==n-1) && size < arr.length ? arr.length: size));  i++;} 
    return out;
}
```

call fn: 
    sp(2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) //2 - child_arrat.length

answer: 
    [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `lodash` and would like a functional programming approach, here is what I come up with:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

function splitArray(array, numChunks) {
  return _.reduce(_.range(numChunks), ({array, result, numChunks}, chunkIndex) => {
    const numItems = Math.ceil(array.length / numChunks)
    const items = _.take(array, numItems)
    result.push(items)
    return {
      array: _.drop(array, numItems),
      result,
      numChunks: numChunks - 1
    }
  }, {
    array,
    result: [],
    numChunks
  }).result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all above might work fine, but what if you have `associative` array with strings as keys?

```
objectKeys = Object.keys;

arraySplit(arr, n) {
    let counter = 0;
    for (const a of this.objectKeys(arr)) {
        this.arr[(counter%n)][a] = arr[a];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one that doesn't alter original array

```js
function splitArray(array = [], nPieces = 1){
    const splitArray = [];
    let atArrPos = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < nPieces; i++){
        const splitArrayLength  = Math.ceil((array.length - atArrPos)/ (nPieces - i));
        splitArray.push([]);
        splitArray[i] = array.slice(atArrPos, splitArrayLength + atArrPos);
        atArrPos += splitArrayLength;
    }
    return  splitArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple recursive function

```js
const chunkify = (limit, completeArray, finalArray = [])=>{
    if(!completeArray.length) return finalArray
    const a = completeArray.splice(0,limit);
    return chunkify(limit, completeArray, [...finalArray,a])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
splitToChunks(arrayvar, parts) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = parts; i > 0; i--) {
        result.push(arrayvar.splice(0, Math.ceil(arrayvar.length / i)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [PartitionJS](https://github.com/RyanMoultrup/PartitionJS) that does exactly this (full disclosure, I wrote it). It will partition an array into as many partition as you specify.

```
const data = [12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1]
const [partitionTwo1, partitionTwo2] = partition().divide(data, 2)
const [partitionThree1, partitionThree2, partitionThree3] = partition().divide(data, 3);
```

Will result in this

```
partitionTwo1 => [12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
partitionTwo2 => [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1]

partitionThree1 => [12, 2, 3, 4]
partitionThree2 => [5, 6, 7, 8]
partitionThree3 => [9, 10, 11, 1]
```

If the divide method is not partitioning the array exactly like you want it to there are additional method to have full control over what goes into each partition by registering callbacks.

```
const nums = [1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

const splitSum = partition()
    .add(i => i < 6)
    .add(i => i > 5 && i < 11)
    .add(i => i > 10 && i < 14)
    .split(nums);

splitSum => [
    [1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12],
]
```

As an added bonus you can also partition arrays asynchronously by spawning a web worker (or web thread in Node), that will partition the array on a separate thread so it doesn't block execution.

```
const reallyBigArray = [1, ... , 1000000]

console.log('--- start ---');

partition()
    .async()
    .add(i => i < 33)
    .add(i => i > 32 && i < 66)
    .add(i => i > 67)
    .split(reallyBigArray)
    .then(result => {
      console.log('Partitions done processing');
    });

console.log('--- UI element loaded ---');

'--- start ---'
'--- UI element loaded ---'
'Partitions done processing'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easy Solutions!!!!**

***Solution 1:***

```
var chunk = function(arr, size) {
   if(arr.length < size) return arr.length ? [arr]:[];
   return [arr.slice(0, size)].concat(chunk(arr.slice(size), size));
};
```

***Solution 2:***

```
var chunk = function(arr, size) {
   let out = [];
   for(let i = 0; i< arr.length; i = i+size) {
      out.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
   }
   return out;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are using lodash, you can achieve it fairly easily like below:

```
import {chunk} from 'lodash';
// divides the array into 2 sections
chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], 2); // => [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11]]
```

Comment: This is wrong. `_.chunk` creates arrays of N elements not N arrays.
Your example would have an output of 6 arrays with 2 elements in each exept the last one ```[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11]]```

Comment: thats what the original question is. please read the expected behaviour in the question.