# Split Array of items into N Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I want to split an Array of numbers into **N** groups, which must be ordered from *larger* to *smaller* groups.

For example, in the below code, split an Array of **12** numbers into **5** Arrays, and the result should be evenly split, from large (group) to small:

```
source: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
  ⬇      
output: [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8] [9,10] [11,12]
```

### [Playground](http://jsbin.com/fotuyuw/edit?js,output)

```js
// set up known variables
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
    numberOfGroups = 5,
    groups = [];

// split array into groups of arrays
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  var groupIdx = Math.floor( i/(arr.length/numberOfGroups) );
  
  // if group array isn't defined, create it
  if( !groups[groupIdx] ) 
    groups[groupIdx] = [];
  // add arr value to group
  groups[groupIdx].push( arr[i] )
  
}

// Print result
console.log( "data: ", arr );
console.log( "groups: ", groups )
```

---

### Update:

Thanks to SimpleJ's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166199/split-a-group-array-of-items-into-n-groups#answer-40166342), I could finish my work.
The use case for this is an algorithm which splits HTML lists into "chunked" lists, a think which cannot be easily achieved by using [CSS Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns).

### [Demo page](http://codepen.io/vsync/pen/ORrJgz?editors=0010)

Comment: I don't understand based on what the array should be splitted? why the 2 first arrays hold 3 numbers and the other hold only 2?
Anyway if you wanted to sort the splitted arrays by their length you can use sort:
`groups = groups.sort(function(g1, g2) {
  return g1.length < g2.length;
})`

Comment: "*I was googling and seeing some other answers but nothing was exactly what I wanted...*" - so what exactly do you want? How do you determine the group sizes, what's the logic? How do existing answers fail to address your requirements? How does your own code fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: @GershonPapi - they are split based the logic to make them as even as possible and yet NEVER to have a larger group after a smaller one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how this should work on different sized arrays with different group counts, but this works for your 12 digit example:

```js
function chunkArray(arr, chunkCount) {
  const chunks = [];
  while(arr.length) {
    const chunkSize = Math.ceil(arr.length / chunkCount--);
    const chunk = arr.slice(0, chunkSize);
    chunks.push(chunk);
    arr = arr.slice(chunkSize);
  }
  return chunks;
}



var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];
console.log( chunkArray(arr, 5) )
```

Comment: btw, why are you using `const` and not `var` which is shorter?

Comment: I just prefer `const` in any case where the variable isn't going to change. `var` or `let` would work fine if you're worried about file size. And `const` will compile into `var` if you're using Babel.

Comment: I see. I do use Babel of course :) Thank you **very** much for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of @SimpleJ answer and without using slice two times.

```js
function splitArrayEvenly(array, n) {
  array = array.slice();
  let result = [];
  while (array.length) {
    result.push(array.splice(0, Math.ceil(array.length / n--)));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(splitArrayEvenly([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more of a mathematical problem than a Javascript.

```
const getGroups = (arr, noOfGroups) => {
  const division = Math.floor(arr.length / numberOfGroups);
  const groups = [[]];
  let remainder = arr.length % numberOfGroups;
  let arrIndex = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < noOfGroups; i++) {
    for (let j = division + (!!remainder * 1); j >= 0; j--) {
      groups[i].push(arr[arrIndex]);
      arrIndex += 1;
    }
    remainder -= 1;
  }

  return groups;
};

const myGroups = getGroups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], 5);
```

myGroups will be [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]

This will work for any number of groups and players

Comment: Thank you, but how is this better than the accepted answer?

Comment: @vsync - Thank you for looking into my answer.

I can say this is a better solution if we compare the complexities.

Complexity of my answer = no of groups * avg no of elements in group, which is 5 * 2.4 = 12 in the given case. 2.4 is because 3 comes twice and 2 comes thrice.

Complexity of accepted answer = no of groups * 2 * length of remaining arr. Here slice is used twice and which I think a heavy operation as it internally iterates through whole array.