# java script split array into multiple arrays using N count

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to split an array by some given count.

```
arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
$scope.arraySpliter(arr);
$scope.arraySpliter = function (a) {
        var arrays = [], size = 3;
        var tempCount = Math.ceil(a.length / 3);

        while (a.length > 0)
            arrays.push(a.splice(0, tempCount));

        console.log(arrays);
    };
```

I want split array like this.
[0,1,2,3][4,5,6,7][8,9,10]

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Also, your split is into 5-element array, 4-element array and 3-element array. Can you explain what this logic is? (and what you mean by "static count", because we're clearly using words differently)

Comment: Also, `4` ends up in both the first and second array?

Comment: Related: [Splitting a JS array into N arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188548/splitting-a-js-array-into-n-arrays)

Comment: Hi, i want to split this array as dividing by given count. as example if i set dividing count as 3, the result should be 3 new arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach:

```js
const splitIn = count => arr => {
  if (count < 2) {return [arr]}
  const first = Math.ceil(arr.length  / count);
  return [arr.slice(0, first)].concat(splitIn(count - 1)(arr.slice(first)))
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log(splitIn(3)(arr))
```

This yields the first four (`ceiling(10 / 3)`) elements as its first group and then recursively splits the remaining six into two groups.  When we get down to splitting into a single group, it simply wraps it in an array.