# Es6: Create an array of objects from a json

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have a json in the below format.

```
    [
    {"id": 1, 
    "name": "peter" },
    {"id": 2, 
    "name": "john" },
    {"id": 3, 
    "name": "justin" }
    .
    .
    {"id": 500, 
"name": "david" },
    ]
```

I am trying to create an array in batches of 10 in the below format

```
[
{
 {"id": 1, 
        "name": "peter" },
.
.
 {"id": 10, 
        "name": "nixon" },
},

{
 {"id": 11, 
        "name": "nancy" },
.
.
 {"id": 20, 
        "name": "underwood" },
}
.
.
]
```

I tried using reduce and tried for loop to loop through it, but was unsuccessful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a JS array into N arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188548/splitting-a-js-array-into-n-arrays)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/457268

Comment: Objects should have key value pairs. You cannot put another object inside `{}` without a key.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo.

```js
const str = "abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
let data = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 26; i++){
  data.push({id : i, name: str.charAt(i)});
}

let res = data.reduce((acc, d) => {
  let groupId = Math.floor(d.id / 10);
  acc[groupId] = acc[groupId] || {};
  acc[groupId][d.id] = d;
  return acc;
 }, {});
console.log(Object.values(res));
```

If you can ensure that id is the same sequence as their position in array, i think simply `slice` will better.